# How to display only certain columns from a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database which has 7 columns and 35 rows. How do I only display only 'n' number of columns at once? Say I want to just see the columns 1,2, and 5. Is there any way to do that using the column names and/or column number? I was using this `print(df['Offenders = Neighbours','Offenders Known'])`, where 'Offenders=Neighbours' and 'Offenders Known' were two of the column names. It worked when there was just one column name but not for more than one. Sounds like a very basic question but I'm new to Pandas so any help would be appreciated

Comment: `df[[Neighbours','Offenders Known']]` ??

Comment: You can also use `.iloc` if you want to reference using column numbers instead of names, eg: `df.iloc[:, [0, 1, 4]]`

Comment: Solved the problem. Thank you

Comment: @Abhishek you might also want to consider trying: `df.filter(like='Offenders')` if there's a common pattern in the names...

Comment: Do you mean column names? Or the values under the column? Because the values under the column are int since they're a count of the number of offenders in a certain area @JonClements

Comment: Column names @Abhishek

Comment: Amazing @JonClements. Just checked and works like a dream